# What are differences between a "panel" a "board" and a "think tank"?

Tags: meaning

I am sorry if my question is stupid, but I can't figure out the difference between these three.

Comment: Well, you might have told us a bit more. It's like saying, what's the difference between: an apple, an orange and an orchard.

Comment: @Lambie it's more like the difference between a bucket, a pail, and a keg.

Comment: @Lambie or a hagfish, a salmon, and a cow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Oxford Dictionary:

[board](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/board)

> A group of people constituted as the decision-making body of an organization.

[panel](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/panel)

> A small group of people brought together to discuss, investigate, or decide on a particular matter, esp. in the context of business or government.

[think tank](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/think_tank)

> A body of experts providing advice and ideas on specific political or economic problems.

A **board** is a group responsible for decision-making in an organization. A board of directors makes all of the central, high-level managerial decisions for a corporation, for example.

I would say that boards and think tanks are both kinds of **panels**, although think tanks stop being considered panels when they are no longer small. Panel is also used when a group of people answer questions for a generalized audience. For example, people who answer questions at a convention due to having inside knowledge of the topic are considered members of a panel. The same would go of a panel that answers government questions fielded by a concerned public. However, this definition of panel is not really related to the one you asked about.

**Think tanks** don't make decisions. They try to solve problems and will likely have an advisory role to whoever needs to make the decisions.

Comment: A think tank is also an organization i.e. usually some kind of not-for-profit association.

Comment: I associate: panel with a small group of people on stage for an hour taking turns discussing s topic, often questions from an audience; a board with permanent positions making decisions for a company; and a think tank with a not for profit org (as @Lambie said), but salaried, intended to write informational articles on a subject.

Comment: boards and think tanks are not kinds of panels. Also, there are things like Board of Medicine, for example, which you didn't address.